# Dynamically autocomplete based on category

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, autocomplete

i have a problem when i am trying to create a autocomplete with dynamic value that based on combobox using codeigniter,
i have tried using ajax and no success.

here is my ajax code for calling item in category

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#jenis").change(function(){              
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>whz/admin/get_item",
            dataType: "html",
            data : "item=" + $("#jenis").val(),
            success: function(data)
            { 
                $("#showitem").text(data);  
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

this is my autocomplete jquery code

```
<div id="showitem">
    <script>
     $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
        <?php foreach ($item as $row){
                echo '"'.$row->item_name.'",';}?>
        ];
        $( "#autotags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
        });
     });
    </script>
</div>
```

and here is my controller

```
public function get_item()
    {
        $this->load->model('whz_model');
        $category = $this->input->post('item');
        $item=$this->whz_model->get_item_by_cat($category);
        $script = '
          $(function() {
            var availableTags = [';
            foreach ($item as $row)
            {
                $script .= '"'.$row->item_name.'",';
            }

        $script .= '];
            $( "#autotags" ).autocomplete({
              source: availableTags
            });
          });';

        echo $script;
    }
```

i am considering using json as another option, but i still don't have enough experience using it.

sorry for bad english,
thanks for your help

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: do you mean that when you enter some value, it doesn't get any ajax response?

Comment: @reza i don't get any error, the code i sent to the view is not working it just showing the code, i tried to use `$("#showitem").html(data);` but nothing happens.

Comment: @RJAnoop yes, it doesn't get any response at all

Comment: @PrimaWinangun I hope it won't enter the `$("#jenis").change(function(){ ` function either.
The **change** event will work when the focus comes out of the field. You should have used **keyup** event instead of **change**. Just check it whether you are getting that ajax call right

Comment: @RJAnoop the ajax is fine but the autocomplete code is not changing, if i change the controller just to show some text it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already fix it with another method i found in the internet, it might be not the best but it works with me,
here is the link

http://www.danielrosca.ro/blog/en/codeigniter-autocomplete/

thank you for all of your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is only based on documentation because I don't have any system handy where I could try.

You are telling jQuery that your AJAX response is `"html"` which means the JavaScript you load will never be executed, I believe. Possibly, it would work if you loaded the data as `"script"` but the better way would indeed be to use JSON.

Your AJAX call would then look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#jenis").change(function(){              
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>whz/admin/get_item",
            dataType: "json",
            data : "item=" + $("#jenis").val(),
            success: function(data)
            { 
                availableTags = data;
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

with a controller like that:

```
public function get_item()
{
    $this->load->model('whz_model');
    $category = $this->input->post('item');
    $item=$this->whz_model->get_item_by_cat($category);

    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($item)));
}
```

You will have to expose the variable `availableTags` globally for this to work which you can achieve by changing your DOM to

```
<div id="showitem">
    <script>
     $(function() {
        availableTags = [
        <?php foreach ($item as $row){
                echo '"'.$row->item_name.'",';}?>
        ];
        $( "#autotags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
        });
     });
    </script>
</div>
```

You might also want to expose it as `window.availableTags`, so you can check it's value in your browser's console.

As mentioned at the start, I did not test this but I believe it should work.

Comment: i have tried your code but still not working, the autocomplete script still showing the default item i set when i load the page for the first time

Comment: Have you tried exposing the variable using
    window.availableTags = availableTags
and checked its value after the AJAX call?

Also, does the AJAX call get the JSON you expect? (Just watch the request in the developer tools of your browser)